# What Is The Simplest Way I Can Get The X Coordinate Of the User?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the user's `x` coordinate location. I don't want an activity fragment or a map, I simply want the coordinate number. I've looked around on stackoverflow and it seems that most of the ways are pretty complicated for a beginner such as myself or need a map activity.

Currently, for my code I have

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        return;
    }
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(longitude) + " , " + String.valueOf(latitude));
```

which seems like it should work. However it crashes the app.

Comment: "it crashes the app" is not very descriptive. If you can't get a proper exception message, have you tried to at least determine which of the code statements is failing? (I have a strong suspicion, but I may be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to **request the permission** after you checked that you in fact do not have it. Hence the app crashed when you tried to get the last known location.

You can request the permissions by calling the following method (To further understand the parameters, check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int))):

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
```

The response to your permission request can be manipulated in the **onRequestPermissionsResult** method.

Here is a messy, albeit a working code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LocationManager lm;
    private TextView textView;

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(longitude) + " , " + String.valueOf(latitude));
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(longitude) + " , " + String.valueOf(latitude));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the location only updates when the app is restarted as there is no location listener implemented in the above code.

I would also like to warn you not to forget to modify the manifest file, stating which permissions you use in your app.